# Yii and .htaccess file on production server

Tags: .htaccess, yii, production-environment

I am new to yii and have some problem in configuring .htaccess file on production server.

**On localhost :**

**Location of Application :** /www/connect_donors/

**Default URL that yii provides is**,

```
http://localhost/connect_donors/index.php?r=controllerId/functionName
```

We used the urlManager in /connect_donors/protected/config/main.php to configure the SEO friendly url's..

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

Now the URL that was working was

```
http://localhost/connect_donors/index.php/controllerId/functionName
```

Then I used the .htaccess file to remove index.php from the above URL.

Location of .htaccess is : /connect_donors/.htaccess

Following is .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /connect_donors
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**URL Chenged to :**

```
http://localhost/connect_donors/controllerId/functionName
```

Everything working fine and awesome.

But yesterday I uploaded the application on production server.

**On Production Server**

Everything remained same only I had to change the .htaccess file.

The .htaccess file on server is,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now the following url:

```
http://donorsconnect.com/
```

loads the home page of server properly.

But,
    http://donorsconnect.com/profile

redirects again to home page.

NOTE : There is no session set on the "profile" controller.

```
class ProfileController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

I tried lot of things, changing the .htaccess file to different codes. but none helped me.

Any help is appreciable.

**Solution**

I finally got the solution and the mistake I had done.

My Components had a request array containing baseUrl.

```
'components'=>array(
        ...
        'request' => array(
            'baseUrl' => 'http://donorsconnect.com',
        ...),
```

Due to this it was not loading. I did not find the real reason for that.

But after removing that 'request' array, its loading fine.

Check link,
http://donorsconnect.com/profile

Comment: Note that,[http://donorsconnect.com/index.php/profile](http://donorsconnect.com/index.php/profile) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not hide index.php like this, read carefully : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

You should set `showScriptName` to false in your main config :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  .....
  'showScriptName'=>false,
  .....
),
```

And your .htaccess should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Yes I have done that, my fill urlManager is as follows,
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            ......
        ),

Comment: Well, this was not obvious. Check your .htaccess file.

Comment: Yeah changed and not working too..Its working on localhost. but not on production server.
Check the link : [http://donorsconnect.com/index.php/profile](http://donorsconnect.com/index.php/profile)

And the new link, without index.php..
[http://donorsconnect.com/profile](http://donorsconnect.com/profile)

Comment: If u ve baseUrl=>'http://example.com' then that can be a problem. I had that problem, I commented that and used yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) to get baseUrl instead. wondering the problem. :)